# How to solve C# exception "The expression must be evaluated for a node set"

Tags: c#, .net

How I can solve this exception:

> System.Xml.XPath.XPathException

My code is:

```
for (var d = 0; d < children1.Count; d++) //lista  doc 1
{
    var child = children1[d];

    XmlNode nodeToFind = root.SelectSingleNode("/data[@name]" + child.Attributes["name"].Value);

    if (nodeToFind == null){}
```

And here is my xml file:

```
<root>
  <data name="senChangePassword" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>Change Password</value>
```

Comment: Do you actually mean `/data[@name='" + child.Attributes["name"].Value + "']`? Are you trying to select the `data` element that has a name matching `child.Attributes["name"]`?

Comment: Exceptions contain details about what happened that can help you fix the error. [Simply stating there was an exception of a given type isn't helpful.](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails) This link will tell you how to get those details to include in your questions.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the value that you are looking for inside the brackets:

```
root.SelectSingleNode("/data[@name='" + child.Attributes["name"].Value + "']");
```

Comment: I have more exception after if(nodetofind == null){result.appendChild(child);} here is Another exception which is System.ArgumentException: 'The node to insert is from another document context.'

Comment: That is a different problem, please post a new question for it, so this question stays on topic of the original issue.